# Reversing words in Arabic

Tags: java

I have codes for fixing Arabic problem in my project, but I'm having some problems with the code,

for example, my code does connect Arabic letters together so they would look fixed, but the main problem it doesn't reverse them, so it only show them connected but not reversed so it will not make since in Arabic.

I had another file which has the reverse and connecting letters thing, but it doesn't work with my the file i'm trying to make fixes in it, so I had the other code which connect the words but not reversing them.

Here is the code :

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class ArabicConv
{
private static final char ALF_UPPER_MDD = 0x0622;
private static final char ALF_UPPER_HAMAZA = 0x0623;
private static final char ALF_LOWER_HAMAZA = 0x0625;
private static final char ALF = 0x0627;
private static final char LAM = 0x0644;

private static final char ARABIC_GLPHIES[][] = new char[][]
        {
                {'\u0622', '\uFE81', '\uFE81', '\uFE82', '\uFE82', 2},
                {'\u0623', '\uFE82', '\uFE83', '\uFE84', '\uFE84', 2},
                {'\u0624', '\uFE85', '\uFE85', '\uFE86', '\uFE86', 2},
                {'\u0625', '\uFE87', '\uFE87', '\uFE88', '\uFE88', 2},
                {'\u0626', '\uFE89', '\uFE8B', '\uFE8C', '\uFE8A', 4},
                {'\u0627', '\u0627', '\u0627', '\uFE8E', '\uFE8E', 2},
                {'\u0628', '\uFE8F', '\uFE91', '\uFE92', '\uFE90', 4},
                {'\u0629', '\uFE93', '\uFE93', '\uFE94', '\uFE94', 2},
                {'\u062A', '\uFE95', '\uFE97', '\uFE98', '\uFE96', 4},
                {'\u062B', '\uFE99', '\uFE9B', '\uFE9C', '\uFE9A', 4},
                {'\u062C', '\uFE9D', '\uFE9F', '\uFEA0', '\uFE9E', 4},
                {'\u062D', '\uFEA1', '\uFEA3', '\uFEA4', '\uFEA2', 4},
                {'\u062E', '\uFEA5', '\uFEA7', '\uFEA8', '\uFEA6', 4},
                {'\u062F', '\uFEA9', '\uFEA9', '\uFEAA', '\uFEAA', 2},
                {'\u0630', '\uFEAB', '\uFEAB', '\uFEAC', '\uFEAC', 2},
                {'\u0631', '\uFEAD', '\uFEAD', '\uFEAE', '\uFEAE', 2},
                {'\u0632', '\uFEAF', '\uFEAF', '\uFEB0', '\uFEB0', 2},
                {'\u0633', '\uFEB1', '\uFEB3', '\uFEB4', '\uFEB2', 4},
                {'\u0634', '\uFEB5', '\uFEB7', '\uFEB8', '\uFEB6', 4},
                {'\u0635', '\uFEB9', '\uFEBB', '\uFEBC', '\uFEBA', 4},
                {'\u0636', '\uFEBD', '\uFEBF', '\uFEC0', '\uFEBE', 4},
                {'\u0637', '\uFEC1', '\uFEC3', '\uFEC2', '\uFEC4', 4},
                {'\u0638', '\uFEC5', '\uFEC7', '\uFEC6', '\uFEC6', 4},
                {'\u0639', '\uFEC9', '\uFECB', '\uFECC', '\uFECA', 4},
                {'\u063A', '\uFECD', '\uFECF', '\uFED0', '\uFECE', 4},
                {'\u0641', '\uFED1', '\uFED3', '\uFED4', '\uFED2', 4},
                {'\u0642', '\uFED5', '\uFED7', '\uFED8', '\uFED6', 4},
                {'\u0643', '\uFED9', '\uFEDB', '\uFEDC', '\uFEDA', 4},
                {'\u0644', '\uFEDD', '\uFEDF', '\uFEE0', '\uFEDE', 4},
                {'\u0645', '\uFEE1', '\uFEE3', '\uFEE4', '\uFEE2', 4},
                {'\u0646', '\uFEE5', '\uFEE7', '\uFEE8', '\uFEE6', 4},
                {'\u0647', '\uFEE9', '\uFEEB', '\uFEEC', '\uFEEA', 4},
                {'\u0648', '\uFEED', '\uFEED', '\uFEEE', '\uFEEE', 2},
                {'\u0649', '\uFEEF', '\uFEEF', '\uFEF0', '\uFEF0', 2},
                {'\u0671', '\u0671', '\u0671', '\uFB51', '\uFB51', 2},
                {'\u064A', '\uFEF1', '\uFEF3', '\uFEF4', '\uFEF2', 4},
                {'\u066E', '\uFBE4', '\uFBE8', '\uFBE9', '\uFBE5', 4},
                {'\u0671', '\u0671', '\u0671', '\uFB51', '\uFB51', 2},
                {'\u06AA', '\uFB8E', '\uFB90', '\uFB91', '\uFB8F', 4},
                {'\u06C1', '\uFBA6', '\uFBA8', '\uFBA9', '\uFBA7', 4},
                {'\u06E4', '\u06E4', '\u06E4', '\u06E4', '\uFEEE', 2},
                {'\u0686', '\uFB7A', '\uFB7C', '\uFB7D', '\uFB7B', 4},
                {'\u067E', '\uFB56', '\uFB58', '\uFB59', '\uFB57', 4},
                {'\u0698', '\uFB8A', '\uFB8A', '\uFB8B', '\uFB8B', 2},
                {'\u06AF', '\uFB92', '\uFB94', '\uFB95', '\uFB93', 4},
                {'\u06CC', '\uFEEF', '\uFEF3', '\uFEF4', '\uFEF0', 4},
                {'\u06A9', '\uFB8E', '\uFB90', '\uFB91', '\uFB8F', 4},
        };
private static final Map<Character, char[]> ARABIC_GLPHIES_MAP;

private static final char HARAKATE[] = {
        '\u064B', '\u064C', '\u064D', '\u064E', '\u064F', '\u0650', '\u0651',
        '\u0652', '\u0653', '\u0654', '\u0655', '\u0656'};

private static final char LAM_ALEF_GLPHIES[][] =
        {
                {15270, 65270, 65269},
                {15271, 65272, 65271},
                {1573, 65274, 65273},
                {1575, 65276, 65275}
        };

static
{
    Map<Character, char[]> arabivGlphiesMap = new HashMap<Character, char[]>();
    for(char[] forms : ARABIC_GLPHIES)
    {
        arabivGlphiesMap.put(forms[0], forms);
    }
    ARABIC_GLPHIES_MAP = Collections.<Character, char[]>unmodifiableMap(arabivGlphiesMap);
}

private static char getLamAlef(char AlefCand, char LamCand, boolean isEnd)
{
    int shiftRate = 1;
    if(isEnd)
    {
        shiftRate++;
    }

    if(LAM == LamCand)
    {
        switch(AlefCand)
        {
        case ALF_UPPER_MDD:
            return LAM_ALEF_GLPHIES[0][shiftRate];
        case ALF_UPPER_HAMAZA:
            return LAM_ALEF_GLPHIES[1][shiftRate];
        case ALF_LOWER_HAMAZA:
            return LAM_ALEF_GLPHIES[2][shiftRate];
        case ALF:
            return LAM_ALEF_GLPHIES[3][shiftRate];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

private static final char getReshapedGlphy(char ch, int off)
{
    char[] forms = ARABIC_GLPHIES_MAP.get(ch);
    if(forms != null)
    {
        if(ch != forms[0])
        {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        return forms[off];
    }
    return ch;
}

private static final char getGlphyType(char ch)
{
    char[] forms = ARABIC_GLPHIES_MAP.get(ch);
    if(forms != null)
    {
        if(ch != forms[0])
        {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        return forms[5];
    }
    return 2;
}

private static String shapeArabic0(String src)
{
    if(src.isEmpty())
        return "";

    switch(src.length())
    {
        case 0:
            return "";
        case 1:
            return new String(new char[] { getReshapedGlphy(src.charAt(0), 0) });
        case 2:
        {
            final char lam = src.charAt(0);
            final char alif = src.charAt(1);
            final char lam_alif = getLamAlef(alif, lam, true);

            if(lam_alif > 0)
                return new String(new char[]{ lam_alif });

            break;
        }
    }

    char[] reshapedLetters = new char[src.length()];

    char currLetter = src.charAt(0);
    reshapedLetters[0] = getReshapedGlphy(currLetter, 2);

    for(int i = 1; i < src.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        final char lam_alif = getLamAlef(src.charAt(i), currLetter, true);
        if(lam_alif > 0)
        {
            if((i - 2 < 0) || ((i - 2 >= 0) && getGlphyType(src.charAt(i - 2)) == 2))
            {
                reshapedLetters[i - 1] = 0;
                reshapedLetters[i] = lam_alif;
            }
            else
            {
                reshapedLetters[i - 1] = 0;
                reshapedLetters[i] = getLamAlef(src.charAt(i), currLetter, false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(getGlphyType(src.charAt(i - 1)) == 2)
                reshapedLetters[i] = getReshapedGlphy(src.charAt(i), 2);
            else
                reshapedLetters[i] = getReshapedGlphy(src.charAt(i), 3);
        }
        currLetter = src.charAt(i);
    }


    final int len = src.length();
    final char lam_alif = getLamAlef(src.charAt(len - 1), src.charAt(len - 2), true);
    if(lam_alif > 0)
    {
        if(len > 3 && getGlphyType(src.charAt(len - 3)) == 2)
        {
            reshapedLetters[len - 2] = 0;
            reshapedLetters[len - 1] = lam_alif;
        }
        else
        {
            reshapedLetters[len - 2] = 0;
            reshapedLetters[len - 1] = getLamAlef(src.charAt(len - 1), src.charAt(len - 2), false);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(getGlphyType(src.charAt(len - 2)) == 2)
            reshapedLetters[len - 1] = getReshapedGlphy(src.charAt(len - 1), 1);
        else
            reshapedLetters[len - 1] = getReshapedGlphy(src.charAt(len - 1), 4);
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(char ch : reshapedLetters)
    {
        if(ch != 0)
            sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static boolean isArChar(char ch)
{
    char[] form = ARABIC_GLPHIES_MAP.get(ch);
    return form != null;
}

public static String shapeArabic(String src)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0, len = src.length(); i < len; i++)
    {
        if(isArChar(src.charAt(i)))
        {
            final int arStart = i;
            for(; i < len && isArChar(src.charAt(i)); i++);
            sb.append(shapeArabic0(src.substring(arStart, i)));
            if(i < len)
            {
                sb.append(src.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sb.append(src.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}


public static final void main(String ... args)
{

    System.out.println(shapeArabic("adfaорфывلاشستيالاشسريلشر شلصاير لريص"));
    System.out.println(shapeArabic("awdhgb شلشس لسشhgasvрпфымв لرشس2323يلسشار"));
    System.out.println(shapeArabic("dashdاتلاي تاسي تاي اتشسر صعغ غلي    ضغعليصض dsaugd"));
}


}
```

I want to make it to reverse the words then connect them, what should I do ? if the other code which reverse the letters needed, please ask, it might have something to give you an idea about what I need.

thank you in advance guys.

Comment: It's a java problem. Could you please remove that `javascript` tag?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. `System.out.println("اتلاي تاسي تاي اتشسر صعغ غلي  ضغعليص");` works for me on its own, without any extra processing. What happens when you run that?

Comment: can you clarify with examples?

Comment: Sorry I removed the Tag,

@jdaz The code were already made by someone, and I used it over the one I have, I don't get why the extra random words are there.

but when I run it, it connect the Arabic words in the project, but it doesn't reverse them, because in the first place the Arabic words are written wrong and not connected, so the code did solve one problem but left the other, I guess there is some reversing code is missing.

Comment: @forthelulx here is an example, https://prnt.sc/suis56

the code does connect words like the first red box, but I want it to reverse the words to be like the green box.

Comment: Screenshots are mainly useless because we can't copy-paste the example.

Comment: @m0skit0

photos were captured inside the project, the 2nd box those are words already reversed before it was inserted so that's why it does look correct, first one were written normally and the code applies its feature to it, so when I copy them they would look weird here.

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
for(int i = 0, len = src.length(); i < len; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = src.length(), len = 0; i > len; i--)
```

Comment: I tried to change it, nothing were wrong in the code, but after compiling inside the project it didn't work, and made the html connected to the code crash

Comment: Yeah you need to change the inner block of code to adapt with this change

Answer (score 2):

`StringBuilder` has a `reverse()` method, so instead of `sb.toString()` you can use `sb.reverse().toString()`.

But in general, you shouldn't need to do so much processing to get Arabic strings to render right. Simply reversing a left-to-right input should be all you need:

```
public static final void main(String... args) {

    String[] arCharsList = new String[]{"م", "ا", "ل", "س"};

    System.out.println(String.join("", arCharsList)); // مالس

    Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(arCharsList));
    System.out.println(String.join("", arCharsList)); // سلام

    Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(arCharsList)); // change back to original

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < arCharsList.length; ++i) {
        sb.append(arCharsList[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString()); // مالس
    System.out.println(sb.reverse().toString()); // سلام
}
```

#### UPDATE

Per the comment below, apparently the issue is that the full words are in the wrong order, not the individual characters. In that case, once you have your string, you can reverse it like this:

```
    String back = "سعيد وقت قضاء لكم نتمنى بالخادم بكم أهلا";
    String[] backList = back.split(" ");
    Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(backList));
    String fixed = String.join(" ", backList);
    System.out.println(fixed); // أهلا بكم بالخادم نتمنى لكم قضاء وقت سعيد
```

Comment: I tried to put sb.reverse().toString() instead and it worked, but I need the word to be switched not reversed in the same place, example of test https://prnt.sc/sukesu

it should be like the green box.

thank you for your comment

Comment: it's like the whole sentence should be reversed, now words with the change it's reversed.

Comment: Yes they are in the wrong order, but where do I put that String, nothing happened when I added it, so I might did it wrongly.

Comment: I still don't think you need the `shapeArabic` function at all, but if you are keeping it, you would replace the last `return sb.toString()` line in your code with `String back = sb.toString()`, then the rest of what I posted above, then `return fixed`.

Comment: I did the changes but it didn't work, the cmd were crashing with question marks, maybe because of the shapeArabic ? but without it, the words would be unconnected, so I'll be back to squire 1, now two fixes were made, first connect letters, the other reverse the letters, now I only need reversing the whole sentence

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I'm sorry, I guess it's my mistake I must've done something wrong that's why it didn't work with me, but if you got time and feel like adding these stuff into my code so I can see what's I missed and try it out again, again thank you :)

Comment: I really can’t tell what else is the problem unless it is just an issue with your Windows console (assuming you are on Windows). Try running your code at [OnlineGDB.com](https://onlinegdb.com) and see if it works. Or, try writing to a file instead of using `System.out.println`.

Comment: The code didn't had errors, but I adjust some of it to adapt, but I only used sb.reverse().toString() for the shapeArabic, and your code "String back =" but I guess I didn't put "String back =" in the right place on my code, please take a look at my code, and if you can put the code in the right place and i'll try it, because I can't run my code on OnlineGDB.com, because it doesn't show me unless I compile and test it out inside the game server.